# how to reduce the space between each mat-grid-tile of the mat-grid-list?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="2:1" > 
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>id FEN</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="idfen" disabled>
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Estado</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="estad_fen">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" matTooltipPosition="after" [matTooltip]="cuadrante">
                <mat-label>Cuadrante</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="cuadrant">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Duración</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="durac">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Comuna</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="comu">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" matTooltipPosition="after" [matTooltip]="nodo">
                <mat-label>Nodo</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="nod">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Cantidad de Servicios</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="cant_ser_afecta">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Fecha Solución</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="fecha_soluc">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Fecha Evento</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="fecha_event">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Clientes FEN</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="cant_client_fen">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Impacto</mat-label>
                <input matInput [formControl]="impac">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>       
    </mat-grid-list>
```

I have tried changing the sizes of the mat-form-field but I have a suspicion that the space is being determined by the mat-grid-title, I have changed the padding but it still doesn't work.
I've also tried overriding the mat-form-field classes, changing the margin and padding but it doesn't seem to be the cause

[image: the white space between those elements is what I want to decrease]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem connected with the `mat-form-field` elements.
Please try to apply this style to the `mat-form-field` elements

**Put this style in your `component.css` file**

```
mat-form-field {
  width: 100%
}
```

And here is the example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5by9v?file=src/app/grid-list-overview-example.html

**UPDATE**

The `mat-grid-list` has tree input properties:

1. **`@Input() cols: number`**: Amount of columns in the grid list.
2. **`@Input() gutterSize: string`**: Size of the grid list's gutter in pixels.
3. **`@Input() rowHeight: string | number`**: Set internal representation of row height from the user-provided value.

So in your case, you need to add the `rowHeight` with the pixel value
for example:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="2px" rowHeight="80px">
   ........
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: if in the wide stackblitz the web happens the same, the white space increases and I also apply the width to my component and the same happens

Comment: @LorenaC.EstrellaR. did you mean the vertical padding?

Comment: @LorenaC.EstrellaR. done. Please check the example. I will update the answer now

Comment: It worked, in the code I was already using heightRow but with radio format not with px. Thank you so much : )

Comment: @LorenaC.EstrellaR. glad to help!